# Execute a Command Once if find Matches Files

Tags: bash, shell, find, freebsd

I've got a script that uses `find`. So far I've been fine using `-exec` to get what I need done, but I'm running into a bit of a roadblock now.

If files are found, I want to execute a command *once* (so `-exec {} \;` isn't what I'm looking for), and it's a command that doesn't take any files as parameters, so `-exec {} \+` won't work (or at least it doesn't with the version of `find` on my FreeBSD 10.1 system.

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pipe the filenames to `xargs`.

I think I missed an important clue here: your command is not interested in the filenames. So you just want to run a command **if** files were found? In that case, you could try something like:

```
find -name nosuchfile | if read; then echo "hello"; fi;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-quit` primary can be used in conjunction with `-exec`, `-quit` is present in both the BSD and GNU `find` implementations.  The example below is constructed to ensure that `find` terminates after the first match, regardless of the exit status of the utility.

```
find path... [expression] \( -exec utility \; -quit -or -quit \)
```